# Disable Proximity Sensor in T-Mobile S5

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-5, proximity-sensor, t-mobile

My new T-Mobile S5 has this "feature" that turns the screen off when anything (including your hand) gets near the screen.

I'm pulling my hair out and I'm going to be returning the phone to T-Mobile if I can't turn this thing off.

To be clear, I need a *T-Mobile S5* answer to this question. There is no option under call settings even peripherally related to the sensor, there is no option under screen even peripherally related to the sensor.

How can I disable this awfulness? I'd prefer suggestions on how to disable it then how to hunt down the engineer who thought this was a good idea so I can knock his teeth out. Barring that, I'll settle for how to disable this idiotic sensor.

Edit: I just wanted to add that any solutions that permanently disable or destroy the proximity sensor will be accepted with open arms. I'd prefer not to have to return the phone if I don't have to.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Normally it should only happen when you're in a phone call.

Comment: Because part of my job includes maintaining and expanding my company's asterisk PBX system. I'm beeping my way through automated phone menus for hours at a time. Having that sensor on makes me want to snap the phone after hour 3.